# Sublime Text 2 Launch ruby file in terminal

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to launch terminal from Sublime Text 2 which would than run **Ruby file** (via Build System). Reason I am not using built in ruby build system is that my ruby script takes input, which does not work in **sublime output panel**.

Does anybody have build system which does this?

Comment: do you mean to set a argument to your .rb file? and can you post your build-system config file ?

Comment: I mean just by pressing `CTRL+B` it opens terminal and runs ruby script. Nothing more.

Comment: if i create a new rb file (and save it!) it works fine. JUst check your build system is set to Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

OK, You could create a file ruby.sh (for example in your home folder):

/home/your/home/ruby.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh
 /usr/bin/xterm -e /bin/sh -c "/path/to/ruby $1; exec /bin/sh" &
```

Create a new Sublime build file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/home/your/home/ruby.sh", "$file"]
}
```

Now when you press CTRL-B your **ruby.sh** should be executed, and that executes **ruby** with your current buffer/file. It opens xterm as a new window (tested).

Comment: If I am not wrong this will give output in Sublime and of course run ruby file. What I am trying to do is open Terminal windows (or CMD prompt window) which would than run ruby code.

Comment: then i would make a shell script. What system your running?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04. is my OS of choice.

Answer (score 0):

About add a custom build-system file, I want to add some specific things.

1 When you create you build-system file, save it in : 
 ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User

PC I'm not sure, perhaps like a directory path :   *...APPDATA/ROAMING/Sublime Text2/ ...*

2 The build-system file 's source code is not complete.  Maybe the following is better:

```
{
    "cmd": ["~/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

More info to:[More info](http://addyosmani.com/blog/custom-sublime-text-build-systems-for-popular-tools-and-languages/)