# Trying to run a simple gets.chomp in Sublime

Tags: gets, chomp

For some reason when I run:

name = gets.chomp

puts name

I get the error:

gets:1:in `<main>': undefined method`chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

If I remove the .chomp and run:

name = gets

puts name

I get no prompt or error, the console just gives me the finished time.  What am I doing wrong?

By the way I'm using Sublime, configured with Ruby

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to run a simple gets.chomp in Sublime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086154/trying-to-run-a-simple-gets-chomp-in-sublime)

Answer (score 0):

You can try run this file in Terminal.  Like this:

> ruby  test.rb

...  #puts name 
 ...

If it runs well, it means your problem is another situation.  You can goto [Sublime Text 2 Launch ruby file in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406613/sublime-text-2-launch-ruby-file-in-terminal)